# When and where to use componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was going through [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) 
I'm unable to understand the purpose of componentDidMount.

I've used render function with a DOM element. When should I use componentDidMount()

Found reactive state. How it helps to update state.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#reactive-state

Comment: I believe  it's basically used for events, ajax requests, some initial behaviours that needs to be destroyed when component is not used (componentDidUnmount) to prevent memory leak

Comment: have a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount